# hibernate query for select * from table where id in (query)

Tags: hibernate

What is hibernate query for below sql?

```
select * from DB_GROUP 
where DB_GROUP_ID in 
(select DB_GROUP_ID from DB_GROUP_ORG where DB_ORG_ID='306132');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify entity column names while using in this query.I used same names what you gave in the table

```
select model from  DB_GROUP  model where model.DB_GROUP_ID 
in 
(select model2.DB_GROUP_ID from DB_GROUP_ORG model2 where model2.DB_ORG_ID='306132');
```